# php on windows exit causes response to abort

Tags: php, windows, exit, abort

So here's the story

Apache + php + Yii framework on windows

In some cases, for example redirect, the framework is calling `exit($status)` where `$status = 0` and it works fine on the linux server, yet on my windows machine it causes response to be Aborted (visible in firebug). Nothing can be found in logs etc. Any ideas why is that?

Here's what Firebug shows (just very basic info, no response at all)

```
URL:POST http://ecosauveur.localhost:8080/index.php/home/login
Status:Aborted
Domain:ecosauveur.localhost:8080
Size:0
IP:127.0.0.1:8080
```

Comment: Can you paste the exact error from firebug?

Comment: Have you tried without passing a `$status` code? How are you running PHP? As FCGI or mod_php?

Comment: is .net installed on your machine???

Comment: now it's apache + mod_php, yet i've run it before with fcgi (IIS7), it can be with or without status, i remember i was trying some kind of flush etc but nothing worked. For previous page i simply commented out the exit on redirect on my local evnironment. Now it's the second page i've got the problem with and this one is mixture of Yii and codeigniter which means more places where exit is called so i'd like to have it solved... I'm considering now updating php (5.3.11->5.3.18) maybe this will help.

Comment: @ArunKillu yes .net is installed

Comment: @buddy It's an odd one certainly, I can't reproduce on Windows/Apache/mod_php 5.4.7 - maybe an upgrade will solve it. Are you using WAMP/XAMPP or did you install separately? If the latter, did you make sure you are running a VC9/10 version of Apache? Running the VC9 builds of PHP from windows.php.net with the VC6 Apache from apache.org is known to problematic.

Comment: @DaveRandom It's VC9 installed separately, I'm guessing it's not very reproducible because i couldn't find anything online so i'm guessing very few people had the same problem. I was just hoping it's something obvious or someone will know right away. Later I'll see if the update will work, right now need to finish the assignment (i already know workaround - comment out the exit;) ).

Comment: @buddy If you are updating, please move on to 5.4 instead of the latest 5.3, 5.3 will be end of life very soon and the sooner everyone migrates the sooner that can happen.